# how to run selenium server and protractor in one command.

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

How can we run protractor and selenium server in one command. Instead of running webdriver-manager start in one terminal and make the server running and in other terminal running protractor protract.conf.js, how can we run both in single command. I am trying to avoid use of gulp.

Answer (score 3):

In your `conf.js` file, if you remove the `seleniumAddress` config option, protractor will automatically do this for you.

**Before**

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
};
```

**After**

```
exports.config = {
  specs: ['spec.js']
};
```

All you would then need to do is run `protractor conf.js` and it will startup the selenium server on random port for you and stop it when test finish.

Comment: @user3085217 if this works could you accept as answer?

Comment: I spent lot of time to achieve something like this and was unsuccessful. Finally your answer helped me. Thanks for your answer. Keep helping fellow testers. I can't use **directConnect** argument as the driver binary like ChromeDriver is an .exe and selenium-server-standalone is a .jar file and webdriver-manager is blocked to download and access these when I say **webdriver-manager update**. Hence needed a way to run selenium server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command in exports.config section of protractor.conf.js file

```
directConnect: true,
```